# Postgres Array Match More than one element

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query to match more than one element in postgres arrays

| Array1 | Array2 | More than one element Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a,b,c,d | a | FALSE |
| a,b,c,d | a,b | TRUE |
| a,b,c,d | a,b,c | TRUE |
| a,b,c,d | a,d | TRUE |
| a,b,c,d | a,c,e | TRUE |
| a,b,c,d | a,b,c,d | TRUE |
| a,b,c,d | a,b,e,d,f | TRUE |
| a,b,c,d | a,z,e,f,g,h | FALSE |

I tried with all of these ops https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html

Is there any inbuilt way to do it?

Comment: What if you have `d,c,b,a` and `a,b,c,d`? (order of elements in an array matter)

Comment: Why is the result on line 4 FALSE? Both `a` and `d` match.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Thank you I have corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a subquery and inside of it unnest both arrays, and then make a cross join with all elements, e.g.

```
SELECT   
  array1, array2,
  (SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE el1 = el2)
   FROM unnest(t1.array1) a1(el1), unnest(t1.array2)a2(el2)) > 1
FROM t t1;
```

**EDIT** (See comments below): In case the array elements do repeat (opposite the given data sample) and you wish to count the overlap only once, just unnest the arrays with another subquery using `DISTINCT`, e.g.

```
SELECT   
  array1, array2,
  (SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE el1 = el2)
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(t1.array1)) a1(el1), 
        (SELECT DISTINCT unnest(t1.array2)) a2(el2)) > 1
FROM t t1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=659bc7bd9dbb261bf97bc7355cb36a0f)

Comment: This query produces wrong results if the array elements are not unique.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm I also thought about it and in fact you're right. I just left this option out because the data sample suggested a different scenario: I edited my question to make your point. thanks for pointing out. cheers and happy coding

Comment: Cheers to you too

Answer (score 2):

Unnest and join the arrays in a scalar subquery; Count the number of resulting rows and check if it is greater than 1.

```sql
select array1, array2, 
  (
    select count(*) 
    from unnest(array1) t1 
    join unnest(array2) t2 on t1 = t2
  ) > 1
from the_table;
```

This is if array elements are unique and the order of elements in the arrays does not matter.

**Update**
To make it work correctly with repeating array elements replace
`unnest(arrayx) tx` with `(select distinct t from unnest(arrayx) t) tx`

```sql
select array1, array2, 
(
 select count(*) 
 from (select distinct t from unnest(array1) t) t1 
 join (select distinct t from unnest(array2) t) t2 on t1 = t2
) > 1 from the_table;
```